# with put request data dosent update in ui without reload page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database

i have an issue .i am doing a project where want to update quantity of product.i am able to sending updated data to database with put request  but my ui desent update .when i reload the page then data updated.If anybody knows how that would be done I much appreciate it

Comment: so your ui uses data from backend, when you send data to backend you either have to store data locally too(let's say you have some global state, to which ui has access), or make get request to backend to get updated data for ui. Reload page makes that get request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.